# How to close android datepicker in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, datepicker

Recently I have created a fingerprint-protected lock screen for my react-native app. Basically, when the user leaves the app and comes back later, this screen pops up. However, yesterday I have discovered that on android, if I open up a date picker, then leave the app and come back again, the date picker is still there:

[image: datepicker]

I am using [react-native-datepicker](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker), which internally uses DatePickerAndroid and TimePickerAndroid.

Is there any way I can close the date picker programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in document itself, it has a method called `onPressCancel()`

So you might need to take reference of datapicker and than calling a method using that reference variable will help. You can just hide the dataPicker in `unmount` or somewhere else.

something like

```
this.picker.onPressCancel();
```

check [reference](https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker#instance-methods)

[image]

Comment: The method you've mentioned is a callback, triggered by pressing the cancel button.

Comment: I think you should read description over there, it is clearly written `onPressCancel - Manually close the date picker panel like, similarly pressing cancel btn`

Comment: The documentation does not say that it only works on ios

Answer (score 0):

Give reference to the date picker

```
<DatePicker
  ref={ref => this.datePicker = ref}
/>
```

to close date picker use this `onPressCancel()` mathod

```
this.datePicker.onPressCancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.listeners = [
        addListener('didFocus', () => {
            console.log("didFocus");
        }),
        addListener('willBlur', () => {
            console.log("willBlur");
            this.datePicker.onPressCancel();
        }),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your onChange Prop

```js
if (Platform.OS !== 'ios') {
   setShowDatePicker(false); /* Or whatever you're using to set the state to false*/
}
```